Select records not in subquery, returns nothing
I have a table with customers and another with documents, I want to get all customers that don't are in the subquery having document type 2
SELECT * from contactos 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * from contactos 
   JOIN documentos ON documentos.cifnif = contactos.cifnif 
   WHERE documentos.idramo = 2 
   AND documentos.estado = 'Vigente'
  )

There are 5000 customers and only 845 on the subquery
But I got an empty result.

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

There is no question in this post. PS When you ask one it will clearly be a duplicate. How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?

Your subquery selects from contactos again, with no correlation to the contactos from the outer query. In other words, it will return the same result for any row of the outer query, and since it always returns something, the outer query will return no rows.
To fix this, you need to remove contactos from the from clause of the inner query, and instead correlate it with the table from the outer query:
SELECT * from contactos 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT * 
   FROM   documentos 
   WHERE  documentos.cifnif = contactos.cifnif AND
          documentos.idramo = 2 AND 
          documentos.estado = 'Vigente'
  )

